# Need help with the following question about finding volume of improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, volume

Find the exact volume of the solid created by rotating the region bounded by $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x\ln x}$ and the $x$-axis on the interval $[2, ∞)$. State the method of integral used.

My issue specifically is that I have no clue how to integrate the integral because I am using the disk method and the integral ends up being
$$\int_2^\infty\pi\cdot\frac1{x(\ln(x))^2}\,dx$$
How would I go about solving this because I am unsure how to integrate that integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see $x(\ln x)^2$ in the denominator, which suggests that the antiderivative involves $\frac1{\ln x}$. And indeed:
$$\int_2^\infty\pi\cdot\frac1{x(\ln(x))^2}\,dx=\pi\left[-\frac1{\ln x}\right]_2^\infty$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}=0$, we get
$$\pi\left[-\frac1{\ln x}\right]_2^\infty=\pi\left(0-\left(-\frac1{\ln2}\right)\right)=\frac\pi{\ln2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply that helps a lot. My malfunction was that I was treating √ ln() as if they were √ +ln() and thus was confused when I squared them because I was using the wrong exponent property.

Comment: @ChaseBlacentosh Please upvote and accept my answer, since you found it useful.

Comment: Don't have the reputation to upvote but your answer in accepted.